# How to get individual data from an item in a list?

Tags: angular

I am trying to get an employee's individual data right after clicking it inside a list of employees. I do get the list but I can't manage to navigate to the component that wil be displaying the data fetched from the employee.
The methods 'getDetail()' and 'getList()' worked fine in Postman but I don't know how to use them to get an item's details from them.
You can find some samples of the codes, I didn't copy every line so some variables are unused here.

**employee-home.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-employee-home',
  templateUrl: './employee-home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./employee-home.component.scss']
})
export class EmployeeHomeComponent implements OnInit {
  employeeForm!: FormGroup;
  roles!: Role[];
  organizations!: Organization[];
  accounts!: Account[];
  employee!: Employee;
  employees!: Employee[];
  showForm: boolean = false;


  constructor(public employeeService: EmployeeService,
              public roleService: RoleService,
              public organizationService: OrganizationService,
              public accountService: AccountService,
              private router: Router) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.employeeService.listEmployees$.subscribe((employees: Employee[]) => {
      this.employees = employees;
    });
    this.employeeService.getList().subscribe((employees: Employee[]) => {
      this.employeeService.listEmployees$.next(employees);
    });

  }
```

**employee.service.ts**

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class EmployeeService extends ApiService {
  listEmployees$: BehaviorSubject<Employee[]> = new BehaviorSubject<Employee[]>([]);
  employee$: Subject<Employee> = new Subject<Employee>();

  constructor(public override http: HttpService) {
    super(http);
  }

  getList(): Observable<Employee[]> {
    return this.get('employee/list').pipe(
      map((response: ApiResponse) => {
        if (response.result && !isNil(response.data)) {
          console.log(EmployeeHelper.fromDto(response.data as EmployeeDto[]))
          return EmployeeHelper.fromDto(response.data as EmployeeDto[])
        } else {
          return [];
        }
      })
    )
  }

  getDetail(employee_id: string): Observable<Employee> {
    return this.get('employee/detail/' + employee_id).pipe(
      map((response: ApiResponse) => {
        if (!(response.result && !isNil(response.data))) {
          console.log(EmployeeHelper.empty())
          return EmployeeHelper.empty()
        } else {
          console.log(EmployeeHelper.fromDtoToEmployee(response.data as EmployeeDto))
          return EmployeeHelper.fromDtoToEmployee(response.data as EmployeeDto)
        }
      })
    )
  }
```

**employee-detail.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-employee-detail',
  templateUrl: './employee-detail.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./employee-detail.component.scss']
})
export class EmployeeDetailComponent implements OnInit {
  employee!: Employee;
  employees!: Employee[];


  constructor(public employeeService: EmployeeService, private route: ActivatedRoute) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {

  }

}
```

**employee-routing.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import {EmployeeHomeComponent} from "./component/employee-home/employee-home.component";
import {EmployeeDetailComponent} from "./component/employee-detail/employee-detail.component";

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'home',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'home',
    component: EmployeeHomeComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'detail/:id',
    component: EmployeeDetailComponent
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class EmployeeRoutingModule {
}
```

**EDIT : **
**employee-home.component.html**

```
<div class="d-inline-flex p-2 bd-highlight">
  <div class="">
    <div>
      <table class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
        <tr>
          <th class="col">Lastname</th>
          <th class="col">Firstname</th>
          <th class="col">Organization</th>
          <th class="col">Role</th>
          <th class="col">Role</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let employee of employees">
          <td>{{ employee.account.lastname }} <button class="btn btn-warning" (click)="goToDetails(employee.id)">Go to</button></td>
          <td>{{ employee.account.firstname }}</td>
          <td>{{ employee.organization.name }}</td>
          <td>{{ employee.role.name }}</td>
          <button class="btn btn-danger" (click)="onDeleteEmployee(employee.id)">Delete</button>
          <button class="btn btn-warning" (click)="onEditEmployee(employee); onShowForm()">Edit</button>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thank you for your help !

Comment: Can you also share the HTML files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been trying to see what could be happening in your code and I think there are a few things that can be improve.

You have this code

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.employeeService.listEmployees$.subscribe((employees: Employee[]) => {
      this.employees = employees;
    });
    this.employeeService.getList().subscribe((employees: Employee[]) => {
      this.employeeService.listEmployees$.next(employees);
    });

  }
```

And it can be replace by this one

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.employeeService.getList().subscribe((employees: Employee[]) => {
      this.employees = employees;
    });
  }
```

if you have a click on the list on the html you can use a function like this one

on the html inside the *ngFor
...

```
<li (click)="goToDetail(employee.id)">{{employee.name}}</li>
```

on the ts

```
goToDetail(employee_id: string) {
this.router.navigate(['/detail', { id: employee_id}]);
}
```

or include it inside the html *ngFor like this without the need of a function

```
<li [routerLink]="['/detail']" [queryParams]="{id: employee.id}" >{{employee.name}}</li>
```

and then inside the detail component you should include the get detail function of your service retrieving the id for the query params. If you need further detail let me know

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I just tried to use it to get the details on the html file 'employee-detail.component.html' but I can't do it. Here's what I tried :  On **employee-detail.component.ts**, in _ngOnInit_, I tried `const employeeId = +this.route.snapshot.params['id'];
this.employeeService.getDetail(employeeId.toString()).subscribe((employee : Employee) => {
      this.employeeService.employee$.next(employee);
    })` but it didn't work and I don't get what to do now

Comment: In this case you're calling for a next and that will lead to the same as the code i commented before. I don't know whats the variable name for the employee detail but let's assume is employeeDetail. in this case instead of `this.employeeService.employee$.next(employee);`  you can do `this.employeeDetail = employee` and to be sure this is returning the correct data you can also do a console.log(employee) so the full code would be like this `this.employeeService.getDetail(employeeId.toString()).subscribe((employee : Employee) => {      console.log(employee); this.employeeDetail = employee   })`